# convert image to byte Matrix

Tags: c#, image, binary-data

I am trying to do a binirazation for an image(png)to get the following result:

[image]

For this I use the following code, but right now I haven't the expected result:

[image]

which gives me the following result[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Xx6.png)

Comment: Dont link pictures, dont post code as pictures.

Comment: That looks like your lines of zeroes are just much longer than you want. I would imagine if you added in scrollbars to your right textbox you could scroll down to see the 1s section of the text. You might just need to add both horizontal and vertical textbars to your text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this, It uses scan lines and lockbits, and its fairly fast.

```
public unsafe static int[,] GetBits(string path )
{
   using (var orig = new Bitmap(path))
   {
      var bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, orig.Width, orig.Height);    
      // lock the array for direct access
      var bitmapData = orig.LockBits(bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

      try
      {
         // get the pointer
         var scan0Ptr = (int*)bitmapData.Scan0;    
         // get the stride
         var stride = bitmapData.Stride / 4;    
         // keep the black around
         var black = Color.Black.ToArgb();    
         //Output
         var array = new int[orig.Width, orig.Height];

         // scan all x first then y
         for (var y = 0; y < bounds.Bottom; y++)
            for (var x = 0; x < bounds.Right; x++)                     
               array[x, y] = *(scan0Ptr + x + y * stride) == black ? 0 : 1;

         return array;    
      }
      finally
      {
         // unlock the bitmap
         orig.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
      }    
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var array = GetBits(@"d:\icon.png");

var w = array.GetLength(0);
var h = array.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
      Console.Write(array[i,j]);
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output**

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00011111111111111111111111111000
00011111111111111111111111111000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000000000000000011000
00011000000000011111111111111000
00011000000000011111111111111000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011000000000011000000000011000
00011111111111111111111111111000
00011111111111111111111111111000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

**Original image 32x32**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To compare two colors, use the `ToArgb` method and better to use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating everytime.
This works for me:

```
var img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
var sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img.Width; j++)
    {
        if (img.GetPixel(j, i).ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb())
        {
            sb.Append("0");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("1");
        }
    }
}

richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

This results in a lot of zeros and some ones, my picture was large so the result was ugly but in your case it should work.